# Why does Field Calculator put in all these 9's?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I’m trying to update some GPS point coordinates in an attribute table using QGIS Field Calculator. However, regardless of whether I do it by creating a new field or updating an existing one, I get about 13 decimal places, the last 5 of which are “9” for every feature. (The original points only had 6 decimal places.) I doubt that this is really a coincidence! It happens even if I stipulate a lower Output field width and Precision. My expression is $y, for example, for latitude.

Any idea what’s going on here?

Comment: I assume you're seeing the data is stored in binary problem where not all values can be precisely stored. Some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

Comment: Thanks, mkennedy, but I'm afraid that discussion is a bit beyond me. So do you have any idea what I can do to make my data look reasonable?

Comment: Here's a clue I just discovered. My original data was NAD 83, so I filled in 2 columns w/ projected data. That went ok. Then I saved the layer as WGS and ran the same expression to get lat/long data. That's when I got all the 9's.

Comment: I had a similar problem here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108336/qgis-2-4-0-chugiak-reduced-real-type-numbers-precision-problem-bug

Answer (score 1):

That definitely sounds like an it's an issue with floating point representation.

Try using `round($y, 6)` instead of just `$y` to round to six digits after the decimal place.