# Reduced real-type numbers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, precision, nextgis

I have a SHP point file created from CSV with QGIS 2.4.0 Chugiak. It contains some data on noise in a certain point. When I import from CSV, it seems to be fine, but when I export to SHP and open the attribute table - the real-type numbers are wrong ("reduced" number). The funny thing is, that when I open this SHP with older QGIS NextGIS 1.8 - everything is fine.

Is it some kind of bug?

I attach the printscreen:

[image: Left is Nextgis, right QGIS Chugiak. The suspicious fields are marked red.]

Comment: when I copy and paste to spreadsheet from QGIS Chugiak, the real numbers look OK.

Comment: It is a classical problem, please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or, with Python: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: I'm just a normal user, not a programmer or system designer. I can set a floating point precision in CSV. It seems to be a software problem (displaying) as the old QGIS does the job. It does not solve why everything else displays the numbers correctly except for QGIS Chugiak.

Comment: It seems that the values are displayed incorrectly only in the attribute table, so the problem is of "less annoyance".

Comment: Thanks for the Python approach, I also tried to round() it but it does not help with the attribute table. But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: OK the rounding worked in 2.4.0 Chugiak, just created a new field with a precision set to 1 and deleted the old field.